# Why can't bars sell their in house brewed beers?

Tags: local, laws

We've got this local bar that brews their own beer but when I tried to buy a bottle to take home they said they were only allowed to serve the in house beer, not sell it. If the state of Florida issued them a liquor license to serve and sell beer, why can't they sell what they make?

Just to be clear by sell I mean sell me a bottle and let me walk out with it.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, so I won't enter this as an answer, but I bet that the situation centers around having a license to _distribute_, which is probably a whole 'nother ball game than just a liquor license.

Comment: Just re-read your question. It is a distribution licensing issue. If they got their commercial distribution license, they could sell you beer. They could also sell it in local grocery stores. It does mean people would not have to come to their bar for their beer though. Could lead to a decrease in sales.

Comment: Can the bar sell you any bottles of third-party beers they serve? If not, then it should not be surprising that theirs is treated differently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most States have two different types of liquor licenses.  On premise and Off premise.  On premise is selling alcohol to drink there, off premise is for taking stuff home.  It is entirely possible that an establishment will only have one or the other.